# Can I resolve a LP problems with optaPlanner

Tags: drools, linear-programming, optaplanner

Good afternoon, I'm a new with optaPlanner, and I want to resolve a basic transportation problem to find the number of units to ship from each factory to each customer that minimizes the total cost, if the answer is yes, How think that the facts are Plants and market, but I don't know how to make the proportional allocation.

Many Thanks!.

Comment: Optaplanner is a heuristic. LP problems are better solved with an LP solver.

Answer (score 1):

> ... find the number of units to ship ...

It sounds like you don't have an LP problem, but an MIP problem. *Unless you can ship 38.14% of a unit, your problem is probably discrete.*

Depending on how fine-grained and course-grained your units are - and the scaling of how many customers you're shipping to - you're better of with a LP solver (fine-grained units, fewer customers) or a heuristic solver such as OptaPlanner (course-grained units, more customers).

OptaPlanner scales well with MIP problems. Furthermore, you don't define the constraints as a set of linear equations, but program the constraints instead, for example as `if` statements in easy java calculation or instead as score rules in drl.

As for doing proportional allocations with OptaPlanner, take a look at [the investment portfolio example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdyIf0JG94Y). In the future, we intend to provide out of the box support for proportional respecting moves.

Comment: A famous result is that solutions to the transportation problem are integer valued automatically, See any book on optimization.So we can formulate as an LP. We can solve it with a MIP solver also, but the MIP solver will be very efficient (only the root node need to be solved).A heuristic seems out of place for a transportation problem (indeed this is a very easy LP).

Comment: Which specific transportation problem are you referring to? Might you have a link? For me, the question isn't entirely clear on the definition of his/her *basic transportation problem* and I can see a number of different use cases fitting.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey for you answer, I start with this solver, I would like to resolve this problem https://www.gams.com/products/simple-example/ in order to learn optaPlanner, actually I have this facts, Plants, Market, and planning variable is Product who has a cost class for cost, It's difficult for me.

Comment: FWIW, Ironically, the quantity variable makes this a non-simple case for OptaPlanner 7.3 or lower. Once we have better support for quantity variable moves out of the box, it will become a simple case too... But now, you'll have to do custom moves like the portfolio investment example.